# Default Timezone is incorrect for only my site when running new Date();

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, timezone

Okay so I am deving a new React site and and playing around with some time stuff and realised that when using the dev tools and running a

`new Date()`

I get back

`Fri Dec 03 2021 03:55:44 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)`

However since I am in the Australian Timezone I expect that this should come back as

`Fri Dec 03 2021 14:55:44 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)`

So my first thought was that my system timezone was out of whack, however when I tried the same on any other website, (open dev tools and run `new Date()`) I get the correct time zoned Date.

My guess of what is going on is that the Date() primitive is being overwritten somewhere but I'm unsure of how to check what is overriding it. I am using the `date-fns` package but that's in terms of date libraries. Below is my `package.json`

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.171",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.14",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.6",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/serialize-javascript": "^5.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "d3": "^6.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.1.6",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "exponential-backoff": "^3.1.0",
    "gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "rrule": "2.6.8",
    "serialize-javascript": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? Also note that in a previous release of my site, that this was not happening and the current site doesn't have this problem, yet rolling back to the previous version that was running doesn't fix the issue and I have tried on multiple clients.

Comment: If you just type `Date` into the dev-tools console, do you get `ƒ Date() { [native code] }` or something else?

Comment: @Phil not getting Native code getting this. Looks like it is being overwritten somewhere

```
class ShiftedDate extends ODate {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      this.nd = new ODate(
        getTime.apply(this) + (Date.prefs[2] - Date.prefs[1]) * 60 * 1000
      );
    }
    //…
```

Comment: The two dates are equivalent, the only difference is that the stringified versions are using different offsets. One is GMT the other is AEDT. The Date object itself has no inkling of timezones, its just an offset from 1 Jan 1970 UTC in milliseconds. E.g. the SO console shows the same as [*toISOString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) but your browser console likely shows the same as [*toString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue, it was actually because I had a chrome extension installed that would overwrite the Time zone for this specific site on localhost for some reason. The way that it works, was by overriding the Date class.
I fixed the issue, by uninstalling/disabling the extension.

Thanks for your help everyone!